# $\prod_{n\geq 0}(1+z^{2n})=\frac{1}{1-z}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

This is a problem of 2.10 of Intro to Complex Analysis by Noguchi

Show that $\prod_{n\geq 0}(1+z^{2n})=\frac{1}{1-z}$

I think there is a typo here as I can multiply $LHS$ by $1-z^2$ and collapsing the terms to get $2$. So in total I get $\prod_{n\geq 0}(1+z^{2n})=\frac{2}{1-z^2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{1-z}$. If one wants to get $\frac{1}{1-z}$, one wants $\prod_{n\geq 1}(1+z^{n})$ instead.

Q. This argument is valid on $|z|<1$ region. How do I get a straightforward argument to $\{|z|=1,z\neq \pm 1\}$ without resorting to analytic continuation?

---

Use $\prod_{n\geq 0}(1+z^{2^n})=\frac{1}{1-z}$ by the same method as above. Then it is solved.

Comment: I think there's more than one typo. Consider $z = \frac{i}{2}$ for example, or $z$ equal to any purely complex number in the unit disk. Then, $1+z^{2n}$ is real for all $n$, but $\frac{1}{1-z}$ is not real.

Comment: If $1+z^{2n}$ is replaced by $1+z^{2^n}$ then the claim is true (for $|z|<1$).

Comment: @carmichael561 Then my solution is wrong as I should have collapsed terms of $z^{2^n}$ form as each time it adds a power of 2. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MichaelLee One has to mind the issue of convergence to an extend as well.

Answer (score 0):

Typo: $z^{2^n}$ not $z^{2n}$. This is also item 2 in Page 193 of Complex Analysis by Ahlfors.

---

Let $P_n$ denote the $n^{th}$ partial product of $\displaystyle\prod_{n=0}(1+z^{2^n})$. Then
\begin{equation}
P_{n}=S_{2^n}
\end{equation}
where $S_n$ is the $n^{th}$ partial sum of the convergent geometric series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$. We prove the assertion by taking the limit of as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: If the index starts at $n = 1$, then the product converges to $\frac{1}{1-z^2}$, not $\frac{1}{1-z}$.

Comment: Then the proof still stands. I edited it to start at 0.

Comment: And the typo in the title is that you have $z^{2^n}$ not $z^{2n}$.